# Dual monitor setup in kubuntu has deadzone in between, how to fix it?

Tags: ubuntu, multiple-monitors, graphics-card, kubuntu, xrandr

10 and have two monitors next to each other (one graphics-card, split DVI cable), they are in portrait mode and the setup with krandr was a snap.

But even though everything displays correctly, when the mouse-cursor travels from one monitor to the other there is a deadzone in between in which the mouse disappears before it reappears.

Also when a window is displayed over both monitors, the middle of the window is simply missing as if there are about 200px that are not displayed.

However maximizing windows works just fine, the borders do not get eaten ...

any ideas what is going on here and how to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using krandr I added:

```
xrandr --output DVI-1 --auto
xrandr --output DVI0 --auto
xrandr --output DVI-1 --rotate left
xrandr --output DVI-0 --rotate left
xrandr --output DVI-1 --left-of DVI-0
```

to my .bashrc, works fine now ..